# Node.js Express middleware function without next

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

In Express middleware, it should be taking 3 parameters: **request, response, next**.
However, in the 2nd middleware in the code where I copied from a book, but only use **request, response.** What is the reason here? and is next optional?

```
var express = require("express");
var http = require("http");

var app = express();

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    console.log("In comes a " + request.method + " to " + request.url);
    next();
});

app.use(function(request, response) {
    response.writeHead(200, { "Content-Type": "text/plain" });
    response.end("Hello, world!");
});

http.createServer(app).listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `express.js` there are 4 types of basic handlers.

- 2 - req, res
- 3 - req, res, next
- 4 - err, req, res, next

If you have 2 arguments, express will always assign a req and res to them, no matter what you call them. It's just a calling convention that is widely used by the express community that makes for cleaner, readable and understandable code.

Comment: Note, that: 
Error-handling middleware always takes four arguments. You must provide four arguments to identify it as an error-handling middleware function. Even if you don’t need to use the next object, you must specify it to maintain the signature. Otherwise, the next object will be interpreted as regular middleware and will fail to handle errors.

Answer (score 22):

`next()` is called when you want the routing for this request to continue onto the next middleware or the next route handler for this request.  It is common to have more than one middleware that might examine a given request so if you did not send a response and want normal routing to continue for this request, then you would call `next()` when you were done with your processing and you want routing to continue.

If you have already sent a response and thus do not want routing to continue, then you do not call `next()`.

It is up to you whether you declare the parameter `next` or not.  If you never intend to call it, then you don't need to declare it as a parameter (it is still passed, but you don't have to declare it if you're not going to use it).

So, you can declare your middleware/requeset handler with parameters `req` and `res` like this:

```
app.use("/someRoute", function(req, res) {
    res.send("hello");
});
```

Or, with parameters `req`, `res` and `next` like this:

```
app.use("/someRoute", function(req, res, next) {
    if (req.query.x) {
        // don't handle this request here, let some other route
        // handler following this handle it
        next();
    } else {
        // send the response, no more route handlers after this
        res.send("hello");
    }
});
```

It makes no difference to Express whether you declare the `next` argument or not.  If you plan on using it, then declare it.  If you don't plan on using it, then there is no reason to declare it, but it is passed anyway.  This is true of all Javascript function arguments.  If you don't declare all the arguments as named arguments, it just makes it harder to access them, but they are still there (for completeness, then can still be accessed through the `arguments` object).

There's also a special case route handler with four arguments `(err, req, res, next)` which is used for error handling (when `next(err)` is called), but that's not what your question is about.  Express does treat route handlers with four arguments declared differently.  It registers them as error handlers.