# How does the 'next' parameter in 'middleware function' work in Node.js' Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on Nodejs and using "Express js", Right now i am working on "middleware function", here is my current code

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

const myLogger = function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('LOGGED')
  next()
}

app.use(myLogger)

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})
```

I am confuse regaring "next" parameter,I have following question regarding middleware function

1. what is use of "next" ? is this redirect to "next middlware function" ? if yes then how ?
2. if there is not "second middleware" exist then what will happen ?
3. if we not use "next" then what will happen ?
4. can we redirect to custom middleware inside "next" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Node.js Express middleware function without next](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42426768/node-js-express-middleware-function-without-next)

Comment: "if yes then how?": IIRC middleware is placed in a stack. `next` calls the next function in the stack.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes, calling next is important because this allows the express.js to move to the next middleware, otherwise it will be in a dangling position and the app will not work appropriately.

2)Your request will reach the route handler and you will get a response with the message 'Hello World"

3)If you don't call next, the request will be terminated and the app will remain hanging

4)Yes, you can redirect to the custom middleware function using next. Whenever next is called with an argument, expresses takes it as an error message. You can define, custom error-handling middleware to direct it according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply `next()` means continue with the first following path matching route. If you never call `next()` or response, the request will be stuck on that middleware. Middleware is there for 2 reasons:

1. manipulating data, you can add extra values into e.g. `request.body` for later uses
2. blocking, if anything is unexpected you can respond without continuing to path matching routes.

For example:

```
// request sent to /users/user1

const myLogger = function (request, res, next) {
    console.log('LOGGED');
    next();
}

router.use(myLogger);

router.post('/users*', (request, res, next) => {
    if (!isAdmin(request)) {
        return res.status(401).json();
    }

    return next();
})

router.post('/users/:id', (request, res, next) => {
    res.json(getUser());
})

function getUser() {
    return { name: 'Lorem', surname: 'Ipsum' }
}

function isAdmin(request) {
    return true;
}
```